# Adding recursion to a function on list addition where the highest and next highest integers are added and then appended to a new list

Tags: python, list, function, recursion

I have a function that is to take a list as an argument and add the highest and next highest integers in said list and then append it to a new list. Here is my attempt at it. I believe there should be some recursion or looping at some point but I am not too sure. Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
#1. Defining the function:
def function_name(list_to_accept):
    #2. Checking that the list_to_accept is a list:
    if type(list_to_accept) != list:
        raise TypeError ('function argument is not a list')
    else:
        #3.this confirms entry is a list, now check that it's not an empty    list
        if len(list_to_accept) == 0:
            raise TypeError ('the list you entered is empty')
        else:
            #4. check that the elements in the list are integers
            for integers in list_to_accept:
                if type(integers) != int:
                    raise TypeError ('element is not an integer')
            #5.the addition that's required takes place here.
            addition_list = []
            clone_list_to_accept = []
            #6.find max(list_to_accept), its index value, pop it out and append to clone list, save it in a variable.
            highest = max(list_to_accept)
            list_to_accept.remove(highest)
            clone_list_to_accept.append(highest) 
            # 7.find the next highest and repeat the move above
            next_highest = max(list_to_accept)
            list_to_accept.remove(next_highest)
            clone_list_to_accept.append(next_highest)

            #8. sum the two highest integers
            integer_sum = highest + next_highest
            #9. append to addition_list
            addition_list.append(integer_sum)

            print (clone_list_to_accept)
            print (addition_list)

integer_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
function_name(integer_list)
```

Comment: What is your question? What results are you seeing? What results are you expecting? It works fine: https://ideone.com/UJ6Xcq

Comment: `I believe there should be some recursion or looping` why? Your code is working as expected, you are finding the two max number and adding them together..... so what's the problem?

Comment: Hi @MooingRawr : I dont want this to run just once. But that for every list reduction after the highest and next highest have been removed.

Comment: @ochekliyeenigbe should have added that to your question. `function_name(list_to_accept)` add that line right under `print(addition_list)` with the same tabbing.

Comment: Might want to check if your list is even numbers and throw the proper errors, you might not even want to throw errors,

Comment: @MooingRawr: You are right about throwing errors in an odd list. I will work on that. But still not clear your previous statement.

Comment: `function_name(list_to_accept)` put that line right under `print (addition_list)` with the same tab spacing so it lines up.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Most of all, give us an example that demonstrates the problem: input, the output your program gives, and the output you want.